# Uploading an image, fits the requirements but failes

Tags: php, image, upload

```
if(isset($_FILES['avatar']) && !empty($_FILES['avatar']['name'])){              
    if($_FILES['avatar']['type'] != "image/gif" || $_FILES['avatar']['type'] != "image/jpeg" || $_FILES['avatar']['type'] != "image/jpg" || $_FILES['avatar']['type'] != "image/pjpeg" || $_FILES['avatar']['type'] != "image/x-png" || $_FILES['avatar']['type'] != "image/png"){
        $errors[] = 'File does not have the right mime type.';
        $errors[] = '(This avatar has the mime type '. $_FILES['avatar']['type'] .')';
    }

    if($_FILES['avatar']['size'] > 40960){
        $errors[] = 'File is too large, max 40 kb.';
        $errors[] = 'This is '. $_FILES['avatar']['size'];
    }
}
```

Hello again stackoverflow!

I let my users decide during registering if they want to upload their avatar right away, or do it later.

What I'm currently trying is to upload a 800b gif file. But when uploading, I get the error that the file does not match the allowed mime types. What do I do here?

Comment: So what does `$_FILES['avatar']['type']` return when you try and upload the file?

Comment: `image/gif`, that's the strange part. @BenFortune

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `||` with `&&`.

Think about it, `||` means `or`. If type is not "image/gif" or type is not "image/jpeg", or ... One of these will be true and you will enter that `if`. For instance, if type is "image/gif" then it is not "image/jpeg" and you will still enter.

More elegantly, replace with `in_array`. For instance,

```
if(!in_array($type, ["image/gif", "image/jpeg"])) // and so on
    $errors[] = 'File does not have the right mime type.';
```

Comment: My brain was melting while I read the answer because of the confusion, but now it all makes sence, and thanks for the tip on elegancy.